# Find an identity expressing $\sin(\cos^{-1}(-t))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find an identity expressing $\sin(\cos^{-1}(-t))$ and determine for what numbers t the identity holds.

I get how to do the first part although not too sure about it, I end up getting $\sin(\cos^{-1}(-t))=\sqrt{1-t^2}$, it is the second part that I was confused about

Comment: This is a question asking you for the domain of a function disguised as a trigonometry problem.

Comment: As a sanity check, note that inverse cosine is defined to output values from 0 to 180 degrees. But sine is never negative for angles between 0 and 180 degrees. By comparison, $\sqrt{1-t^2}$ is never negative. So the two formulas agree in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $t\in[-1,1]$ otherwise the root does not exist.